# Is it possible to draw links between nodes in the user interface?

Tags: netlogo

I wish for the user of the program to be able to draw out the network upon which turtles can travel around to broaden the scope of the program. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. In NetLogo's Models Library, in the Code Examples section, there are several examples of different kinds of mouse interaction. Look for the word "mouse" in the example name.